# Is there an equivalent to roff's .ns (no-space mode) in plain TeX?

Tags: plain-tex

Is there something like roff's `.ns` in plain TeX (or something even better)? E.g. a command which says that the directly following `vskip`s are ignored or (additional) a special "`vskip`" which makes all adjacent `vskip`s to zero?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you add some examples to illustrate what you mean?

Comment: Lets say one wants to start each paragraph with some vskip. But when the paragraph is the first after a heading this vskip should be ignored. Of cause this can be done with e.g. a flag which is set or cleared after a heading, it is just an example for application of a vskip ignore command.

Comment: You can use `\lastskip`.

Comment: @egreg can you turn this comment into an answer, too? (as you see, I'm doing some housekeeping this afternoon :o)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

LaTeX has the macro `\addvspace` for this; perhaps this is not really what you want, because it will add the larger space resulting from comparing the two consecutive ones, which is usually what's wanted. For instance, say a list always has some vertical space before it; if it follows a section title, probably the space after the section title is larger than the one before the list. On the contrary, if a list follows `\smallskip`, the larger skip would be that of the list. So the list will start with `\addvspace` or, for the plain TeX macros I propose below, with `\addvskip`.

```
% latex.ltx, line 1462:
\def\addvspace#1{%
  \ifvmode
     \if@minipage\else
       \ifdim \lastskip =\z@
         \vskip #1\relax
       \else
       \@tempskipb#1\relax
         \@xaddvskip
       \fi
     \fi
  \else
    \@noitemerr
  \fi}
```

to be supplemented by `\@xaddvskip`

```
% latex.ltx, line 1448:
\def\@xaddvskip{%
  \ifdim\lastskip<\@tempskipb
    \vskip-\lastskip
    \vskip\@tempskipb
  \else
    \ifdim\@tempskipb<\z@
      \ifdim\lastskip<\z@
      \else
        \advance\@tempskipb\lastskip
        \vskip-\lastskip
        \vskip \@tempskipb
      \fi
    \fi
  \fi}
```

In plain TeX you don't have minipages to take care of, so this can be simplified.

The macro issues an error message (the wrong one, but the team had memory constraints at the time LaTeX2e was released, so they just chose one that could possibly help) if not called in vertical mode.

What does it do? In a minipage nothing, so let's look at the other cases. It uses `\lastskip` to retrieve the amount of the last skip (it returns zero if the last item is not a skip); if zero is returned, the stated skip is issued and ends its job. Otherwise it loads a scratch skip register with the stated amount and calls `\@xaddvskip`.

This macro in turn checks whether `\lastskip` is less than the stated amount; in this case it issues `\vskip-\lastskip` to kill it and issues the desired skip. Otherwise it looks whether the stated skip is negative and does nothing if also `\lastskip` is negative; otherwise it adds `\lastskip` to the stated amount, kills `\lastskip` as before and issues the sum.

An implementation for Plain TeX could be as follows:

```
\catcode`@=11
\newskip\@addvskiptemp
\def\addvskip{\afterassignment\@addvskip\@addvskiptemp=}
\def\@addvskip{%
  \par % \vskip implies \par
  \ifdim\lastskip=\z@
    \vskip\@addvskiptemp
  \else
    \@addvsk@p
  \fi
}
\def\@addvsk@p{%
  \ifdim\lastskip<\@addvskiptemp
    \vskip-\lastskip
    \vskip\@addvskiptemp
  \else
    \ifdim\@addvskiptemp<\z@
      \ifdim\lastskip<\z@
      \else
        \advance\@addvskiptemp\lastskip
        \vskip-\lastskip
        \vskip\@addvskiptemp
      \fi
    \fi
  \fi
}
\catcode`@=12
```

Test file (add the code above at the start):

```
abc\smash{\vrule depth 2.9\baselineskip}
\vskip2\baselineskip
abc\smash{\vrule depth 2.9\baselineskip}
\vskip\baselineskip
\addvskip2\baselineskip
abc

\bye
```

The rules are for showing the spaces are the same.

[image]

Note that Plain TeX already has `\removelastskip`, and a simplified version could be

```
\catcode`@=11
\newskip\@addvskiptemp
\def\addvskip{\afterassignment\@addvskip\@addvskiptemp=}
\def\@addvskip{%
  \par % \vskip implies \par
  \ifdim\lastskip<\@addvskiptemp
    \removelastskip
    \vskip\@addvskiptemp
  \fi
}
\catcode`@=12
```

if you don't plan to have negative skips around.

Answer (score 1):

You can prepere the `\vvskip` macro which does vskip only from first usage (in one place in the document):

```
\let\orivskip=\vskip
\def\vvskip{\par \ifdim\lastskip=0pt \expandafter\orivskip
                 \else \bgroup \afterassignment\egroup \dimen0=\fi
}
```

And you can set `\let\vskip=\vvskip` in order to apply this behaviour to all `\vskips`. But this solution doesn't do absolute control of all vskips in the document because there are many vskips not created by `\vskip` primitive: from `\parskip`, around display math etc.